# Run u-boot command at startup

Tags: u-boot, yocto

I have a custom board running Yocto (Jethro) and would like to run a single u-boot command, preboot.  Obviously, breaking the boot sequence with space and running it manually works.  How do I get it to run automatically?  More specifically, where is the startup command sequence, by default?

Edit: Also, I am aware I can edit the environment at runtime.  However, I am trying to build this change into the image so I can distribute it.

Answer (score 4):

When you are in the uboot environment. Enter `printenv`, it will list the environment variables that uboot uses.

There is a variable name `bootcmd`. Currently, mine contain a bunch of if else command. Similarly, add your prefer function there for boot.

And after it is finished and tested. Use `saveenv` to store the edit

Here is a [syntax](http://www.denx.de/wiki/view/DULG/CommandLineParsing) for uboot.

Edit:

> U-Boot allows to store commands or command sequences in a plain text file. Using the `mkimage` tool you can then convert this file into a script image which can be executed using U-Boot's `autoscr` command.  [U-boot Scripting Capabilities](http://www.denx.de/wiki/view/DULG/UBootScripts)

Comment: Yeah, that works, but then that is only that disk.  How do I automatically build it into the image?

Answer (score 2):

Typically, your U-Boot recipe will build U-Boot for a single machine, in that case, I'd normally just patch the compiled in, default, U-Boot environment to do the right thing. This is achieved by

```
 SRC_URI_machine += "file://mydefenv.patch"
```

Or (even better) use your own git tree. This would also have the additional benefit that your system might be able to boot up and to something useful, even if the environment would be totally corrupted.

Another possibility is to do it like Charles suggested in a comment to another answer, create an environment offline, and have U-Boot load it, see [denx.de/wiki/view/DULG/UBootScripts](http://www.denx.de/wiki/view/DULG/UBootScripts)

A third possibility, that I've also used sometimes, is to construct the environment offline (possibly using the same or a similar mechanism as in the link above), and the flash the environment to flash during the normal flash programming process. Though, most of the time I've done this on AT91's, using a tcl script similar to [at91 Sam-Ba TCL script](https://www.embeddedrelated.com/showthread/AT91SAM/4018-1.php)

No matter which method you chose, the `bootcmd` variable in U-Boot should hold your boot script.

Answer (score 1):

The general answer is that bootcmd is run by default, and if there is persistent environment you can change the command and 'saveenv' so that it's kept.

Answer (score 1):

It is easiest to modify the said `bootcmd`, which is executed anyway.

As an alternative to patching the kernel, it is possible to override the command in u-boot. 
Create a file e.g. `platform-top.h` at the same place where you would place the patch file (it might already exist) and override the `CONFIG_BOOTCOMMAND`.

The result will look something like this:

```
/* ... */

/* replace the memory write with any other valid command */
#define CONFIG_BOOTCOMMAND "mw 0x1 0x1 && run default_bootcommand"
```

Don't forget to make the file known in your bbapend `SRC_URI = "file://platform-top.h"`